# IPv6 and ESP as a next header

Tags: networking, ipv6

I'd like to know how to parse IPv6 header and get offset to TCP header and its payload.

I know that IPv6 has fixed base header. I know also that there are several extension headers in IPv6 - among others: routing, fragment, destination options, ESP, etc.

What I got is the pointer to buffer with ethernet frame.
Now I can find beginning of IPv6 header, but cannot calculate beginning of TCP header and its payload in case when there is ESP header. There is some rfc2406 describing the ESP, but it is not clear for me. I cannot calculate the size of ESP header and its data, so I cannot find out the offset of TCP.

My question is: how to calculate the length of the ESP extension header in case of IPv6?

Answer (score 0):

In general each extension header starts with two bytes indicating the type of the next header and the length of the current header.

You cannot assume this to be true in general though. It depends on the type of extension header you are parsing, that type was indicated by the next header field in the previous header.

The length field is interpreted slightly different in IPSec compared to other IPv6 extension headers.

For a normal IPv6 extension header you get from the byte value to the length of the header by first add 1, then multiply by 8.

for an IPSec header you get from the byte value to the length of the header by first add 2, then multiply by 4.

**Why it was designed like this**

The receiver of a packet need to validate the length field of the packet as it is being processed. IPv6 requires all extension headers to be a multiple of 8 bytes in length such that it can be implemented efficiently on 64 bit CPUs.

The extension header has a minimum length of 8 bytes, and though the extension header has no maximum length, it would be invalid for an extension header to claim to extend beyond the end of the packet it is embedded within.

Getting any of these validations incorrect would most likely lead to a serious security problem. For example if a receiver would blindly accept an extension header claiming to be 0 bytes long, it would cause the parsing to assume the next extension header started at the exact same address. This could lead to an infinite loop where the receiver keeps parsing the same extension header over and over. It would be quite likely for this to have triggered an instant freeze of the OS if such a corrupt packet was received.

But by requiring the receiver to add 1 and multiply by 8, two of the validations are no longer required because regardless of which byte value in the range 0 through 255 you apply this calculation to, it will produce a result which is at least 8 and is a multiple of 8. As an added benefit it increases the possible extension header size from 255 bytes to 2048 bytes.

The receiver still has to validate the maximum length, there is no way around that. Any packet with a valid extension header could be corrupted by decreasing the payload length field in the primary header to be too short for the extension header.

**Why IPSec is different**

IPSec is used over both IPv4 and IPv6. But IPv4 in general only requires 4 byte alignment (optimized for 32 bit CPUs) where IPv6 requires 8 byte alignment (optimized for 64 bit CPUs). For that reason the multiplier is only 4 in that case. The minimum length of the header is still 8 bytes though.

This means that when IPSec is used over IPv6, the receiver has to verify that the length field is an even byte value. However assuming the CPU architecture is capable of accessing unaligned values (at reduced performance), the risk in case the developer forgot this particular validation is minor. At worst a corrupted packet will require a few more CPU cycles to process.

**Using this to find the payload header**

The following pseudocode shows how to process the headers.

```
Initialize a pointer to the first byte of the IPv6 header.
Initialize the header type to 41.
While the header type is a known IP or extension header:
    Compute current header length
    Process current header if applicable
    Copy next header field from current header
    Move pointer forward by current header length
```

In this algorithm header types 4 and 41 are special in that they indicate IPv4 header and IPv6 header.

Comment: I know in general how to parse extensions headers, but I've got problem only with ESP, because it is not fixed length. Do you have any ideas how to compute its length to skip it? I'd like to skip it because I don't need any content from it, but only have to now the offset where is the next extension header.

Comment: @user2699113 You should not assume that any extension headers are fixed length, you should be using the length field wherever it exists. I didn't recall that the IPSec headers were as different as they are. I am more familiar with the AH header, and what I wrote is entirely accurate for the AH header, but not for ESP. I'll take another look on the spec and either update or delete this answer.